# Group acting freely on tree

Tags: gr.group-theory, order-theory, group-actions

A tree is a connected acyclic (symmetric) graph. A group acts freely on a graph if there are no inversion of edges and stabilizers of vertices are trivial.
The Bass-Serre Theorem states that A group is free if and only if it
acts freely on a tree.

An ordered tree is a partially ordered set $(T,\leq)$ such that

1) for all $t\in T$, the set $\{u: u\leq t\}$ is totally ordered, and

2) every pair of elements has a lower bound.

For instance, every totally ordered set is a tree.

Are there versions of the Basse-Serre Theorem in the case where a group acts freely on an ordered tree?

Comment: In your definition of an ordered tree, you should add the "root", I think, i.e. (3) $T$ has a minimal element (lower bound for all elements), otherwise $\mathbb{Q}$ (with the usual order) would be a tree and we would have an action of this tree on itself by translations (which are all strictly increasing). The trees needed for the Basse-Serre Theorem (save the trivial case) are at least denumerable.

Comment: If I've understood your definition correctly, then the Cayley graph of any left-orderable group gives a free action of a group on an ordered tree. There are far too many left-orderable groups to admit any sort of reasonable structure theory.

Comment: "Bass-Serre", not "Basse-Serre". Refers to Hyman Bass.

Comment: One should restrict to ordered trees with some connectedness assumption (but no root: free actions on the real line should be acceptable).

Comment: @HJRW: There is a description of left orderable groups. These are precisely subgroups  of Homeo$(\mathbb{R})$. The question is whether there is a similar "largest group" among groups acting freely on ordered trees. It  does make sense. But of course Bass-Serre type results are impossible.

Comment: @MarkSapir, sure, although there's also a cardinality restriction.  But in any case, the subgroups of  $\mathrm{Homeo}(\mathbb{R})$ are in many ways mysterious!  So I still maintain that there's no "reasonable structure theory".